# hide options in comboBox java swing

Tags: java, swing, duplicates, jcombobox

I'm wanting to create the option for users in a game to select their own piece to play with from a list of piece's that I have made. To do this I have two comboBox's that contain the same items in them but i dont want users to be able to select the same piece.

I have thought about removing the item from comboBox 1 if selected in comboBox2 (and adding it back later) but i am using the index of the selected item later when i assign the image to the 'player' class and so this would get messy there and also the indexing of each list would be different since they dont contain the item that the other has selected (hope that makes sense).

How can i make the item in comboBox 2 hidden or unselectable if it is selected in comboBox 1?

Many thanks

Comment: Wrap up all the information need for the piece into a POJO of some kind, use this as the items within the combobox, then the index doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create POJO which represents the basic properties of the `Piece`...

```
public class Piece {

    private Image image;
    private String name;

    public Piece(String name, Image image) {
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Add these to your `JComboBox`

```
Piece[] pieces = new Piece[]{
    // Create what ever pieces you need...
}
DefaultComboBoxModel modelPlayer1 = new DefaultComboBoxModel(pieces);
DefaultComboBoxModel modelPlayer2 = new DefaultComboBoxModel(pieces);

JComboBox cbPlayer1 = new JComboBox(modelPlayer1);
JComboBox cbPlayer2 = new JComboBox(modelPlayer2);
```

You will find that you will probably need a `ListCellRenderer` of some kind in order to display the name of the `Piece` in the `JComboBox`, for example...

```
public class PieceListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (value instanceof Piece) {
            value = ((Piece)value).getName();
        }
        return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    }

}
```

Then apply the renderer to the comboboxes

```
cbPlayer1.setRenderer(new PieceListCellRenderer());
cbPlayer2.setRenderer(new PieceListCellRenderer());
```

Now, you don't need to care about the indecies, and because you've built the two models from the same array of `Pieces` you should have no issue simply removing them by reference...

```
Piece p = (Piece)cbPlayer1.getSelectedItem();
((DefaultComboBoxModel)cbPlayer2.getModel()).removeElement(p);
```

See [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more details

Comment: duplicates are (only) possible (directly) with POJO